# git merge origin - always defaults to tracking branch?

Tags: git, git-merge

Say I have a script that does something like:

```
git fetch origin

git branch | while read b; do
   git checkout $b
   git merge origin
done
```

my question is - will git always know what to do with the `git merge origin` command, assuming that all branches are tracked by the remote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... will git always know what to do with the `git merge origin` command ...

Git will always do *something*.  Probably not what you want, though!  You probably want:

```
git checkout $b
git merge $b@{upstream}
```

which is *not* what will happen.

When Git is resolving a string like `master` or `origin/develop` or `MERGE_HEAD` to a commit hash ID, it follows the rules described in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).  In particular, there are six steps used.  The first checks for a file in the `.git` directory.  The third step checks for a tag name, and the fourth checks for a branch name.

Please follow the link above and examine each of the six steps listed under the **SPECIFYING REVISIONS** section, and think about what happens when Git tries `origin` at each step.  For instance, at step 1, Git will check for a file named `.git/origin`, which (presumably) won't exist.  Note that step 6, when applied to the literal string `origin`, checks for your `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`.  Now run:

```
$ git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
```

to see what hash ID you get.  This tells you how `git merge origin` is going to behave.

(To see how to change the hash ID associated with `refs/remotes/origin/HEAD`, see [the `git remote` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html), particularly the `set-head` sub-command.  But use the `@{upstream}` notation instead.)

Comment: Ok cool, so the `@{upstream}` thing is real syntax right? That will be useful, thanks

Comment: Yes: search that same documentation for `@{upstream}`.

Comment: I am confused, if I do `git fetch origin; git merge HEAD@{upstream}` is that right for the current branch? the reason I am doing fetch, instead of git pull, is that I want to fetch multiple branches, not just my current branch.

Comment: Yes, `HEAD@{upstream}` means the same as `<current_branch>@{upstream}` or just `@{upstream}`. `HEAD` itself changes contents, from whatever it had before to `ref: refs/heads/<name>` on each `git checkout <name>`. So if the upstream of `br1` is `origin/branch`, then after `git checkout br1`, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref @{upstream}` prints `origin/branch`.